# Angular set debounce time on a button

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I would like to set a debounce time on a button from my HTML in Angular.
This is the code I already have.

```
    const button = document.getElementById('mybtn') ;
      const click$ = fromEvent(button, 'click');
      const debounceClick$ = click$.pipe(debounceTime(500));
      debounceClick$.subscribe(() => {
         console.log('debounceClick$');
      });
```

Somehow I can't run the program as I get this compile error:

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:23:32 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FromEventTarget<Event>'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'FromEventTarget<Event>'.
```

I'm would like to have a compile ready code which also gives me the desired result.
Desired result: button only clickable every 500ms

Comment: It's unusual to see `debounce` on a button - more common to see `throttleTime`

Answer (score 4):

`document.getElementById()` is not guaranteed to return an element since the provided identifier might not exist on the page. Because of this, TypeScript types the return value as `HTMLElement | null`.

You need to let the TS compiler know that `button` will not be `null` since `fromEvent` doesn't accept `null` as a first argument.

You could use an `if` statement:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('mybtn');

if (button != null) {
    // button's type should now be just HTMLElement
    const click$ = fromEvent(button, 'click');
    // ...
}
```

Or you could could assert that you know `button` will exist using the [non-null assertion operator (`!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```js
const button = document.getElementById('mybtn');
const click$ = fromEvent(button!, 'click');
// ...
```

Of these approaches, the `if` statement is more robust. You don't know if the user or another script will have removed `button` from the DOM, so you shouldn't assert you know it's non-null.

---

One other thing, unless you're using `click$` somewhere, you don't need it as a standalone variable. You can achieve the same result like this:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('mybtn');
const debounceClick$ = fromEvent(button, 'click')
    .pipe(debounceTime(500));

debounceClick$.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('debounceClick$');
});
```